# Angular 2: Display images & Code/Style text. How?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to start learning Angular 2 by creating simple layout for an application like twitter where my only goal to create the main Home layout which i named "Work Space" this application uses HTML, CSS, Bootsrap and Angular 2 with other library like code-prettify to styles the code.
I have some problem need to be fix which is:

1) The image for ProfileImage div did not display in html page ?

2) how i can post and display the code as it is without using something < for < sign...etc. How i can do it ?

3) if i try to use the component to display the content div as it is with all the styles init instead of add it directly into html page it will display without style so i can use *ngFor to display each post. How can i fix that ?

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl:'./app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = "Work Space";
    
    isFavorite = false;
    isLike = false;

    likeClick() {
        this.isLike = !this.isLike;
    }
    favoriteClick() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div id="titleBar">{{ title }}</div>
<div id="PostShow">
    <div id="PostHeader" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="ProfileImage" class="col-xs-1"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="ProfileImage" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></div>
        <div id="NameTags" class="col-xs-9">
            <div id="ProfileName" class="col-xs-12"><strong>iSporty</strong></div>
            <div id="ProfileTags" class="col-xs-12">C#, AngularJS 2, Web Developer</div>
        </div>
        <div id="PostTime" class="col-xs-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 6m</div>
    </div>
    <div id="PostContent">
        <b>Bootstrap Grid System</b>
        <p>Bootstrap's grid system allows up to 12 columns across the page. If you do not want to use all 12 columns individually, you can group the columns together to create wider columns. Bootstrap's grid system is responsive, and the columns will re-arrange automatically depending on the screen size.</p>
        <b>Grid Classes</b>
        <p>The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:
            <br/>
            <strong>xs</strong> for phones, <strong>sm</strong> for tablets, <strong>md</strong> for desktops, <strong>lg</strong> for larger desktops.
            <br/> The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.</p>
        <b>Basic Structure of a Bootstrap Grid</b>
        <p>The following is a basic structure of a Bootstrap grid:</p>
        <div class="panel panel-default CodePanel">
            <div class="panel-heading CodeHeadingColor">
                Bootstrap Code:
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body CodeBodyColor">
                <pre class="prettyprint">&lt;div class="row"&gt;
  &lt;div class="col-*-*"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class="row"&gt;
  &lt;div class="col-*-*"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="col-*-*"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="col-*-*"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class="row"&gt;
  ...
&lt;/div&gt;</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PostImage">PostImage</div>
    <div id="PostFooter" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="PostLikes" class="col-xs-1">
            <i class="fa RedColor" [class.fa-heart-o]="!isLike" [class.fa-heart]="isLike" (click)="likeClick()">
            </i> 15</div>
        <div id="PostComments" class="col-xs-1"><i class="fa fa-commenting"></i> 200</div>
        <div id="PostFavorites" class="col-xs-1">
            <span class="glyphicon YellowColor" [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite" [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite" (click)="favoriteClick()">
            </span> 5
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7"></div>
        <div id="PostDots" class="col-xs-2"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="PostShow">
    <div id="PostHeader" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="ProfileImage" class="col-xs-1"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="ProfileImage" style="width:60px;height:60px;"></div>
        <div id="NameTags" class="col-xs-9">
            <div id="ProfileName" class="col-xs-12"><strong>Ray DOM</strong></div>
            <div id="ProfileTags" class="col-xs-12">JavaScript, Adobe Creative Suite, App Developer</div>
        </div>
        <div id="PostTime" class="col-xs-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 5h</div>
    </div>
    <div id="PostContent">
        <b>C# - Basic Syntax</b>
        <p>C# is an object-oriented programming language. In Object-Oriented Programming methodology, a program consists of various objects that interact with each other by means of actions. The actions that an object may take are called methods. Objects of the same kind are said to have the same type or, are said to be in the same class.</p>
        <p>For example, let us consider a Rectangle object. It has attributes such as length and width. Depending upon the design, it may need ways for accepting the values of these attributes, calculating the area, and displaying details.</p>
        <p>Let us look at implementation of a Rectangle class and discuss C# basic syntax:</p>
        <div class="panel panel-default CodePanel">
            <div class="panel-heading CodeHeadingColor">
                C# Code:
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body CodeBodyColor">
                <pre class="prettyprint">using System;
namespace RectangleApplication
{
   class Rectangle 
   {
      // member variables
      double length;
      double width;
      public void Acceptdetails()
      {
         length = 4.5;    
         width = 3.5;
      }
      
      public double GetArea()
      {
         return length * width; 
      }
      
      public void Display()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
         Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
         Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
      }
   }
   
   class ExecuteRectangle 
   {
      static void Main(string[] args) 
      {
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
         r.Acceptdetails();
         r.Display();
         Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
   }
}</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PostImage">PostImage</div>
    <div id="PostFooter" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="PostLikes" class="col-xs-1">
            <i class="fa RedColor" [class.fa-heart-o]="!isLike" [class.fa-heart]="isLike" (click)="likeClick()">
            </i> 3</div>
        <div id="PostComments" class="col-xs-1"><i class="fa fa-commenting"></i> 40</div>
        <div id="PostFavorites" class="col-xs-1">
            <span class="glyphicon YellowColor" [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite" [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite" (click)="favoriteClick()">
            </span> 20
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7"></div>
        <div id="PostDots" class="col-xs-2"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```css
body {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}
#titleBar {
    color: #c7c7c7;
    background-color: #2d2d30;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #007acc;
}
#PostShow {
    color: #c7c7c7;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#PostHeader {
    padding: 5px 0 5px;
}
#ProfileImage {
    padding: 0 10px 0;
}
#ProfileName,
{
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#PostTime {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
#PostContent {
    padding: 5px 30px 5px;
}
#PostImage {
    padding: 0 0 5px;
}
#PostFooter {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top: solid 1px #434346;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #434346;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#PostLikes,
#PostComments,
#PostFavorites {
    text-align: left;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#PostDots {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px 10px 0 0;
}
.RedColor {
    color: #DF0101;
}
.YellowColor {
    color: #D7DF01;
}
.CodePanel {
    background-color: #007acc;
    border: 2px solid #007acc;
}
.CodeHeadingColor {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007acc;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.CodeBodyColor {
    background-color: #1d1f21;
    padding: 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have done some work on the code but i still have some problems init which is Image dose not display Also when i display the code using *ngFor it will display in a single line not like previous one so i still need some help here. please ?

Comment: First question fixed by changing image path to "app/images/logo.png". but other problems not yet. Hopefully i will be able to do it with more tests.